# Powershell Get-ChildItem most recent file in directory

Tags: powershell

We produce files with date in the name.
(* below is the wildcard for the date)
I want to grab the last file and the folder that contains the file also has a date(month only) in its title.

I am using PowerShell and I am scheduling it to run each day.  Here is the script so far:

```
  $LastFile = *_DailyFile
  $compareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
  $LastFileCaptured = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$LastFile.LastWriteTime        
         -ge $compareDate}
```

Answer (score 222, accepted):

If you want the latest file in the directory and you are using only the `LastWriteTime` to determine the latest file, you can do something like below:

```
gci path | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
```

On the other hand, if you want to only rely on the names that have the dates in them, you should be able to something similar

```
gci path | select -last 1
```

Also, if there are directories in the directory, you might want to add a `?{-not $_.PsIsContainer}`

Comment: @user977645 remeber to accept this as answer clicking on the v sign on the left under the upvote/downvote arrow

Comment: There is a rumor on the internet that "LastAccessTime" works for this.  It is a lie.  Your solution is the correct one.

Comment: For the first file: | sort LastWriteTime | select -first 1

Comment: Forgive me snowcode,if I misunderstood your post, but I believe you are incorrect.  The newest file is received by -last 1, not first 1.  I tested this myself I have files as new as today, and as old as 2019.  When I run the above code with -last 1, I do get todays file.  When I change it to -first 1, I get the oldest file, the one from 2019.

Comment: `-file` if you only want files.

Comment: Why has @snowcode 's comment upvotes although it is incorrect as tellurye explained. I flagged the comment for moderator's attention. Thanks TelluRye, upvote!

Comment: @techspartans what do you mean with 'first file'?

Comment: @Timo first file in the sorted list if your folder contains more than one file. Here I am sorting based on the LastWriteTime, which means latest file will be the first file in the list.

Comment: No, `-first -1` file will be the last one.

Comment: Once we get the file, using above accepted code, how then do we copy it to somewhere?

Answer (score 15):

#### Try:

```
$latest = (Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1)
$latest_filename = $latest.Name
```

#### Explanation:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory *.txt | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1


    Directory: C:\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                
-a----         5/7/2021   5:51 PM           1802 Prison_Mike_autobiography.txt
```

- `Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory *.txt` or `Get-ChildItem` or `gci` : Gets list of files ONLY in current directory. We can give a file extension filter too as needed like `*.txt`. Reference: [gci](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/file-gci/), [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1)
- `Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime` : Sort files by LastWriteTime (modified time) in descending order. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.1)
- `select -First 1` : Gets the first/top record. Reference [Select-Object / select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7)

#### Getting file metadata

```
PS C:\Temp> $latest.Name
Prison_Mike_autobiography.txt

PS C:\Temp> $latest.DirectoryName
C:\Temp

PS C:\Temp> $latest.FullName
C:\Temp\Prison_Mike_autobiography.txt

PS C:\Temp> $latest.CreationTime
Friday, May 7, 2021 5:51:19 PM


PS C:\Temp> $latest.Mode
-a----
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes I think this would be quicker.

```
Get-ChildItem $folder | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime -Top 1
```

Comment: I like the idea of sorting in descending order, then taking the first result. Depending on how it works behind the scenes, that could be faster on a large directory. But you need to pipe to Select. Also, Top is not valid. `Get-ChildItem $folder | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select -First 1`

Comment: Yeah my bad, -Top was only introduced in PowerShell 6

Answer (score 6):

@manojlds's answer is probably the best for the scenario where you are only interested in files within a root directory:

```sh
\path
     \file1
     \file2
     \file3
```

However, if the files you are interested are part of a tree of files and directories, such as:

```sh
\path
     \file1
     \file2
     \dir1
         \file3
         \dir2
              \file4
```

To find, recursively, the list of the 10 most recently modified files in Windows, you can run:

```
PS > $Path = pwd # your root directory
PS > $ChildItems = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -File
PS > $ChildItems | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 10 FullName, LastWriteTime
```

Comment: This worked for me when trying to find out if a SharePoint library with a lot of folders was being actively used. In order to use the script though I had to open the library in file explorer with IE, go back to the site root, single click on the library folder, in the home tab of the ribbon -> Copy Path

Answer (score 2):

You could try to sort descending "sort LastWriteTime -Descending" and then "select -first 1." Not sure which one is faster