# Efficiently finding an extremum

Tags: sorting, powershell, max

A [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675658/powershel-get-childitem-most-recent-file-in-directory) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210649/how-to-find-newest-file-in-directory-using-powershell-script) to "how do I find the newest file" is:

```
dir | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
```

This isn't efficient for a large number of files.

Is there a built-in way to efficiently find extrema?

Answer (score 3):

The fastest method I know of to accomplish that for a large directory is:

```
(cmd /c dir /b /a-d /tw /od)[-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

And for something a bit more .NET programmer-ish:  :-)

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::First([Linq.Enumerable]::OrderByDescending((new-object IO.DirectoryInfo $pwd).EnumerateFiles(), [Func[IO.FileInfo,DateTime]]{param($f) $f.LastWriteTime}))
```

This will return the full .NET FileInfo object.  It seems to perform on the same order as @mjolinor's solution - in limited testing.

Comment: Nice!  (although I think I'd still us mine and just run the result through Get-Item if I needed the full object).

Comment: @mjolinor Your solution is definitely a lot less to type and way more likely to be used.  :-)  Just wanted to advertise the use of LINQ here as a somewhat interesting alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
$newest = $null
dir | % { if ($newest -eq $null -or $_.LastWriteTime -gt $newest.LastWriteTime) { $newest = $_ } }
$newest
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. The function `Max`:

```
function Max ($Property)
{
    $max = $null
    foreach ($elt in $input)
    {
        if ($max -eq $null) { $max = $elt }

        if ($elt.$Property -gt $max.$Property) { $max = $elt }
    }

    $max
}
```

can be used to define `Newest`:

```
function Newest () { $input | Max LastWriteTime }
```

It can be called as such:

```
dir | Newest
```

It can also be used to define `Largest`:

```
function Largest () { $input | Max Length }
```

E.g.:

```
dir -File | Largest
```

Similarly, `Min` can be used to define `Oldest` and `Smallest`:

```
function Min ($Property)
{
    $min = $null
    foreach ($elt in $input)
    {
        if ($min -eq $null) { $min = $elt }

        if ($elt.$Property -lt $min.$Property) { $min = $elt }
    }

    $min
}

function Oldest () { $input | Min LastWriteTime }

function Smallest () { $input | Min Length }
```