# How to get the real LastWriteTime of a directory?

Tags: windows

LastWriteTime of a Directory only updates if a new file is created,
not when one updates

```
PS>mkdir foo

PS>Get-Item ".\foo" | select -ExpandProperty lastwritetime
Friday, February 12, 2016 1:56:18 PM

PS>"hello" > .\foo\hello.txt
PS>Get-Item ".\foo" | select -ExpandProperty lastwritetime
Friday, February 12, 2016 1:56:53 PM

PS>"line 2" >> .\foo\hello.txt
PS>Get-Item ".\foo" | select -ExpandProperty lastwritetime
Friday, February 12, 2016 1:56:53 PM

PS>"a new file" >> .\foo\hello1.txt
PS>Get-Item ".\foo" | select -ExpandProperty lastwritetime
Friday, February 12, 2016 1:57:55 PM
```

How do I get the time when a directory changed ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675658/powershell-get-childitem-most-recent-file-in-directory it will get the time of latest modified file.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to recurse through all the files.