# How Jenkins can copy new file from given folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins. I have given remote path to folder with already builded setups inside - filenames can vary. I need to monitor that folder for new file and copy it to my workspace (and then deploy and execute some auto tests against them).

Question is how to recognize that I have a new file (this will be my trigger to start whole process) and how to store that new file filename in variable - to copy it later?

Is that even possible in Jenkins? Maybe it is a plugin for that already?

Jenkins is working on windows machine.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that file under source control? If so which?

Comment: Out the box it will trigger off a few triggers none that will suite you. You can try something like https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Files+Found+Trigger  Its possible to trigger a build from a script so you could write a script to monitor the folder for the file and trigger your build. If the process that puts the file in that directory is also a jenkins project then you can trigger your build from that build.

Comment: It is a regular windows folder, and I have no influence to process that builds the files.

Comment: Try with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the filesystem scm plugin and set up source polling to trigger your job. 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/File+System+SCM

Of course that doesn't solve the issue of what the new file is. If you are using powershell a good solution is here: [Powershell Get-ChildItem most recent file in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675658/powershell-get-childitem-most-recent-file-in-directory)