# get modified date of subfolder within folder

Tags: powershell

There are about 1000 share folders, and I need to find out when they are last modified.
So, these share folders contain subfolder and user can modify data in those subfolder.

I have a script that can get the last modified date of parent folder but it is not giving the correct data.

```
$CSVFilePath = Get-Content "C:\RA\main.txt"
$outputsss = "C:\RA\output.csv"
foreach ($fileName in $CSVFilePath) {
    echo $fileName;
    if (Test-Path $fileName) {
        $d = Get-ItemProperty -Path $fileName -Name LastWriteTime
        $times = $fileName + " - " + $d.LastWriteTime
        $times
    }
    $times | Out-File $outputsss -Encoding utf8 -Append
    #Get-Content $filename | Out-File $outputsss -Encoding utf8 -Append
}
```

Is there any way I can get the last modified datetime of share location?

Comment: What is the incorrect data and the data you're expecting?

Comment: @Manu e.g i have 10 folders parent name is A and inside parent i have other 9 folders and in those 9 folders more folders could be there. If any one of them get updated then how can i get the modified date. because if i check the modified date of A then it won't show correct date.

Comment: I doubt it doesn't show the correct date, although it might not show the date you expect. Updates on the last modification time of folders don't work recursively. [Related](https://superuser.com/q/147524). [Also related](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_time_update.html).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i found one question which can help in this situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675658/powershell-get-childitem-most-recent-file-in-directory but not able to get it worked. Can you have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried multiple times and below is the script that helped me. I need to verify it because it is still running.

```
$CSVFilePath = Get-Content "C:\RA\main.txt"
$outputsss = "C:\RA\output.csv"
foreach($fileName in $CSVFilePath)
{
echo $fileName;
If (Test-Path $fileName) {

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Recurse  -Path $fileName | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.LastWriteTime

    #$d = Get-ItemProperty -path $fileName -Name LastWriteTime
    $times = $fileName + " - " + $latest.LastWriteTime
$times
    }
$times |Out-File $outputsss -Encoding utf8 -append

}
```

I hope it worth for someone.