# Powershell find latest file and open in file explorer

Tags: powershell, scripting

This is based on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9675811/14529561.

How would I pass the result from `gci path | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1` and open with explorer.exe?

I have tried:

```
$wd = gci path | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1;
explorer $wd

gci path | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | Format-Table -hidetableheaders | explorer $_.

gci path | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | Format-Table -hidetableheaders | ii $_.
```

Unfortunately, all the above give me give me errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the `PSParentPath` property.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path path |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
        Select-Object -Last 1 | Foreach-Object {
                Invoke-Item $_.psparentpath
        }
```

Comment: May I ask you to not use cmdlet aliases even though the OP does so in this case. Writing the full cmdlet names will make your code easier to understand for others that may have similar questions.

Comment: Thanks Doug,
Unfortunately I don't have the option to use `Invoke-Item $_.psparentpath`

Comment: Using  part of the code from Hackoo (below) worked.
`Foreach-Object { Explorer /n,/select,$_.FullName }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

---

```
$Mypath=$Env:Temp
gci $Mypath | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | % { Explorer /n,/select,$_.FullName }
```

---

And if you want to explore in more than folder, you can put thel into an array and do like this :

---

```
cls
$Mypath=@("$Env:UserProfile\desktop","$Env:Temp","$Env:AppData")

ForEach ($P in $Mypath) {
    gci $P | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | % { Explorer /n,/select,$_.FullName }
}
```